# How do you convert a string timestamp to a UTC date that I can display, in go?

Tags: date, go, type-conversion

I am trying to display an array of timestamps in human readable form. Array comes from db, and I send it into the template, where the iterations happens.

`t.Timestamp` is a string, comes from the db

I tried `t.TimeStamp = strconv.Atoi(t.TimeStamp)` and error came up: *multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context*

I don't understand why it does that. If someone could help me figure this out, please?
Also if you know a better and quicker way of turning a string timestamp into a UTC date, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strconv/#Atoi`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) returns multiple values.

```
func Atoi(s string) (i int, err error)
```

You need to check for the error value.

```
ts, ok := strconv.Atoi(t.TimeStamp)
if ok != nil {
  ts = 0
}
```

Speaking of timestamp and db, you can check out the [mgo/bson project](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson).
It has a [`Timestamp` class](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#MongoTimestamp) used in [`timestamp.go`](https://github.com/MongoHQ/seed/blob/master/timestamp.go).

From a `int64` timestamp, you can use [`time.Unix()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) to get a [`Time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time).

And you can then [format that Time](http://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2011/05/go_time.html).

```
t := time.Unix(ts, 0)
fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700"))
```